# 計算した平均値に標準偏差を足すと最大値を超えてしまう

Tags: python, numpy

以下の百分率を示す、配列が与えられたとします。

```
test = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.8571428571428571, 0.7142857142857143, 0.8571428571428571, 0.8571428571428571, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])*100
```

平均値と標準偏差を算出すると以下のような結果になりますが、標準偏差を考慮すると100%を超えてしまいます。これは何がおかしいのでしょうか。

```
np.mean(test) # 92.857..
np.std(test)  #  9.58314..
```

Comment: 与えられた引数を母集団全体とみなした場合の標準偏差を計算してみましたが、この値は正しいと思います。
何が100%を超えてしまうのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問された方が提示している形（分かりやすいように昇順に変更）

```
test = np.array([71, 86, 86, 86, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100])
# test.mean() + test.std() = 102.52 > 100
```

を，数学的に示すのは（私には）難しいですが，

```
test2 = np.array([86, 86, 86, 86, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100])
# test2.mean() + test2.std() = 101.26 > 100
```

の形なら，数学的に示せそうです。つまり，命題は
「異なる実数 `a, b (a < b)` のみを含み，それぞれの個数が `k, m (0 < k < m)` 個の集合では `mean + std > b` となる」
です。

まず，「平均値が `0` 」の条件を加えて考えます。

```
a0, b0 (a0 < 0 < b0), k, m (0 < k < m)
(a0 * k + b0 * m) / (k + m) = 0  ->  a0 * k + b0 * m = 0
```

が条件なので

```
r = -a0 / m = b0 / k (r > 0)
```

とおけて， `a0 = -r * m` が `k` 個， `b0 = r * k` が `m` 個と書けます。次に，分散（標準偏差の2乗）を求めると

```
var = {(a0 - 0)^2 * k + (b0 - 0)^2 * m} / (k + m)
    = {(-r * m - 0)^2 * k + (r * k - 0)^2 * m} / (k + m)
    = r^2 * k * m * (m + k) / (k + m)
    = r^2 * k * m
    > r^2 * k * k  because: m > k > 0, r > 0
    = (r * k)^2
```

となります。よって，標準偏差は以下の条件を満たします。

```
std > r * k = b0
```

ところで，この平均値が `0` の集合の全ての要素に同じ任意の実数を加算した集合を考えると，標準偏差は変わらず加算値が平均値となります。従って，この集合では

```
mean + std > mean + b0 = b
```

となり，上記の命題が示されました。

Answer (score 3):

標準偏差は平均からその範囲の値の中に全体の68％の値が入る数(データの平均との差の2乗の平均に対して平方根をとるもの)とのことなので、下に引っ張られていても上にも同じように膨らんでしまいます。なので何もおかしくありません。

・参考リンク
https://data-viz-lab.com/standarddeviation

Comment: より正確には、正規分布を仮定するとそのようになります。今回は値の範囲が 0 以上 100 以下に閉じているので正規分布にはなりません。なりませんが、近似を考えていると思うことはできます。